# How do I display font awesome v6.4.2 brand icons in angular?

Tags: angular, font-awesome

It is a fresh project with angular and font-Awesome.
I am missing something not sure what it is.

The imports and adding the reference.

Version of Fontawesome

```
  "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
```

```
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
imports: [
    FontAwesomeModule,
  ],
```

```
  "styles": [
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
```

```
html code 
<i class="fa-brands fa-space-awesome"></i>
```

Does not show anything

I tried a version 4 of Font-Awesome and it showed the icons.

Comment: Since you are using the Angular Fontawesome library, you need to migrate your HTML code to use the `FaIconComponent`: `<fa-icon [icon]="faCoffee"></fa-icon>` Refer to [usage](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome#usage)

Answer (score 0):

add below package and import.

```
@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
```

Import your icon from

```
import { faSpaceAwesome } from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";
```

on your **.ts** file create a variable

```
public faSpaceAwesome = faSpaceAwesome;
```

and in **.html** file add below tag.

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faSpaceAwesome"></fa-icon>
```